# Error message that reads "ValueError: 'Ã' is not in list" when executing script that encrypts/decrypts strings in French

Tags: python

```
import sys

def read(a):
    encrypted_messages_list = []
    with open(a) as encrypted_messages_file:
        encrypted_messages_list = encrypted_messages_file.readlines()
        encrypted_messages_list = [line.strip() for line in encrypted_messages_list]
    return(encrypted_messages_list)

a = sys.argv[1]
left_shift = int(sys.argv[2])
encrypted_messages_list = read(a)

# create a list of characters of the alphabet
alphabet = list(("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÀÂÇÉÊÈËÎÏÔÜÛÙabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzâêîôûéàèùëïü"))

alphabet_left_shifted = []
for alphabet_index in range(len(alphabet)):
    shifted_index = (alphabet_index + left_shift) % len(alphabet)
    alphabet_left_shifted.append(alphabet[shifted_index])

decrypted_messages_list=[]
for line in encrypted_messages_list:
    newline=''
    for character in line:
        if character!=' ':
            index = alphabet.index(character)
            newline=newline+alphabet_left_shifted[index]
        else:
            newline = newline+' '
    decrypted_messages_list.append(newline)

for line in decrypted_messages_list:
    print(line)

with open('decrypted_messages.txt', 'w') as decrypted_messages_file:
    for line in decrypted_messages_list:
        decrypted_messages_file.writelines(line+'\n')
```

This Python program encrypts/decrypts the English alphabet perfectly fine, but as soon as I replace it with the French alphabet, I run into errors when debugging.

The entire error message reads:

```
C:\Users\ssmith\Downloads>python main.py file.txt 3
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ssmith\Downloads\main.py", line 30, in <module>
  index = alphabet.index(character)
    ValueError: 'Ã' is not in list
```

Comment: In your own words, do you expect `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzâêîôûéàèùëïü"` to contain `'Ã'`? Why? What do you think should happen when an attempt is made to look for the `'Ã'`? Why?

Comment: No, 'Ã' should not be included in the alphabet list because it is not part of the French alphabet. I don't even know why it's giving me this error when 'Ã' doesn't even belong in the list of letters.

Comment: "I don't even know why it's giving me this error when 'Ã' doesn't even belong in the list of letters." That's **exactly why** it gives you the error. The *message you are trying to encrypt* has that letter. That isn't a `' '` (the only thing you tried to handle specially), so it must be looked up within `alphabet`. It isn't there, so an error occurs.

Comment: There are no encryptions with 'Ã' in them. All encryptions use letters that can be found within the alphabet list.

Comment: Yes, it does. At least when you use `codecs.open(a)` to read it. The computer is telling you that it does.

Comment: Sorry, I should have deleted the "codecs" part. It should just be "with open(a)..."

Comment: Does the problem still occur if you delete the first half of the file? What if you only keep that half and delete the rest? Repeat cutting down the file until you have as small a file as you can get that still causes the problem, then show us the file contents.

Comment: This is not a [example]. An [example] should include enough data to reproduce the issue, including the content of the example file (besides, reduce unnecessary parts in the code)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the character Ã (and all other characters that you might come across on the French alphabet) on your alphabet list located right under the comment `# create a list of characters of the alphabet`

Comment: I tried that, and it's still giving me the same error. I made sure to include every possible letter in French in the alphabet list, including upper and lower case ones with accent marks and such.

Comment: @SallySmith do you get an error on any other letter?

Comment: Nope, so far this is the only letter that I've seen come up repeatedly in the error.